# Linker error undefined reference (Прошу помощи)

Tags: c++, компоновщик

"Проект" из 3-х файлов. Заголовок с объявлением структуры (head.h), определение функции (pillow.cpp) (члена структуры), и main() (файл main.cpp)

Компилятор ругается на ссылку без определения функции (?), 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `beef::pillow()'

но если включить в main файл определение (через #include) он начинает ругаться на двойное определение структуры.
head.h conflicting declaration 'typedef struct beef beef' 
'beef' has a previous declaration as `typedef struct beef beef'

В чем моя ошибка?

```
//head.h  
typedef struct {void pillow();}beef;

//pillow.cpp
#include "head.h"
#include iostream

using namespace std;

void beef::pillow()
{cout << "pillow\n";}

//main.cpp
#include "head.h"
#include iostream
#include "pillow.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
beef f1;
f1.pillow();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include "pillow.cpp"` - и что вы этим добились? В результате у вас дважды компилируется реализация... И зачем это извращение `typedef struct {void pillow();}beef;`?

Comment: Вы читали описание вопроса? Если не включаю pillow.cpp, он пишет одну ошибку, если включаю - другую

Comment: Вы читали мой ответ? Вы делаете ерунду в сАмом определении типа структуры...

Comment: typedef использовал из-за рекомендации в книге, (проверил, видимо актуально только для с, чтобы не писать struct каждый раз).

Answer (score 1):

**head.h**

```
#pragma once
struct beef
{
    void pillow();
};
```

**pillow.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "head.h"

void beef::pillow()
{
    std::cout << "pillow\n";
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "head.h"
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    beef f1;
    f1.pillow();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Вот так. В проекте должны быть оба файла - и `pillow.cpp`, и `main.cpp`.

Обратите внимание, как правильно определять структуру в C++.

Comment: Про #pragma once не знал, учту. Но почему компилятор ругался на undefined reference to `beef::pillow()' Даже когда в main определение (pillow.cpp) не было включено?